# The use of 恩着せがましい with と思う in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I understand most of the below sentence, but when I get to 恩着せがましいと思うのではないか, things get confusing.

日本人は人見知りが激しいので打ち解けあうまでは時間かかりますが、仲良くなると恩着せがましいと思うのではないかと思います。

My translation: A Japanese person's shyness is intense, so it takes a long time to get close to them, but I think that if you do, they might think you are condescending.

Is my translation right? If not, what would be the correct translation and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 仲良くなると恩着せがましいと思うのではないかと思います, the subject of 恩着せがましい is 日本人 and the subject of the first 思う is the reader, so it's basically saying:

I think that once you do, YOU might find THEM condescending.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have no idea why somebody gave it a thumbs down. It made perfect sence to me. I think that I just forgot who the subject of the sentence was, as I was reading it. Again, thank you for your answer.